# Sending a post request behind a proxy server using idHTTP

Tags: http, delphi, proxy

i am having a problems sending a post request behind a proxy server with IdHTTP and IdSSL,

not sure if there is something missing in my code or with the proxy server and post, i've done my best.
i get sometimes error 10061 connection refused, connection timed out.

using Delphi XE8

```
 var
  Params: TStrings;
  lHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  IdSSL: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin
 TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(procedure   ()
  begin
   Params := TStringList.Create;

   lHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
   try
      IdSSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(lHTTP);
       IdSSL.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1_2;
       IdSSL.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvSSLv3];
      lHTTP.IOHandler := IdSSL;
      lHTTP.HandleRedirects := True;

       Params.Add('username=myuser');
       Params.Add('password=mypass');

      try
        lHTTp.ProxyParams.ProxyServer := '177.104.200.15';
        lHTTp.ProxyParams.ProxyPort := 35923;
        lHTTp.ReadTimeout := 60000;
        lHTTp.Connect('instagram.com', 80);
        lHTTP.Request.Accept := '*/*';
        lHTTP.Request.AcceptLanguage := 'en-US,en;q=0.5';
        lHTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
        lHTTP.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0';
        Reply := lHTTP.Post('https://Instagram.com/login', Params);

         TThread.Synchronize(TThread.CurrentThread,
          procedure()
            begin
             memo3.lines.add(reply);
            end);


          IdSSl.Free;
          lHTTP.Free;

     except on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
       begin
         TThread.Synchronize (TThread.CurrentThread,
          procedure ()
            begin
             memo3.lines.add(E.ErrorMessage);
            end);
       end;
     end;

  except on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
       begin
         TThread.Synchronize (TThread.CurrentThread,
          procedure ()
            begin
             memo3.lines.add(E.ErrorMessage);
            end);
       end;
  end;
 end).Start;
end;
```

**UPDATE**

Error message : `First chance exception at $751A2502. Exception class EIdOSSLUnderlyingCryptoError with message
'Error connecting with SSL.
error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number'.`

**UPDATE2**
using

```
IdSSL.SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv23; // enable all available versions first
IdSSL.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := IdSSL.SSLOptions.SSLVersions - [sslvSSLv2, sslvSSLv3];
```

gives the Error : `error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol'.`

Comment: Can you access the server with your web browser? Can you post to other servers (for example https://httpbin.org/)?

Comment: i can not @mjn42

Comment: What kind of proxy are you actually using?  The `TIdHTTP.ProxyParams` property only works with HTTP proxies (and HTTPS requires the proxy to support the `CONNECT` HTTP method). For other proxies, like SOCKS, you have to assign an appropriate component (like `TIdSocksInfo`) to the `TIdHTTP.Socket.TransparentProxy` property instead (after assigning the `TIdHTTP.IOHandler` property first).

Comment: i did, but another error message, check update please, what is wrong !! @RemyLebeau

Comment: @P.R: You are not configuring the SSLIOHandler correctly. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Error connecting with SSL.
>   error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:**wrong version number**

That error means you are not using an SSL/TLS version that the target HTTPS server is willing to accept.  That is why the handshake is failing.  This has nothing to do with using a proxy.

In your code, you are setting **BOTH** the `SSLOptions.Method` and `SSLOptions.SSLVersions` properties. **DON'T DO THAT!**  They are mutually exclusive, setting one updates the other.  You are setting `SSLOptions.Method` to `sslvTLSv1_2` first, but then you are setting `SSLOptions.SSLVersions` to `sslvSSLv3`, which will change `SSLOptions.Method` to `sslvSSLv3` to match.  Thus, you are trying to connect to the HTTPS server using SSL 3.0, which many servers no longer accept because it has been compromised.

Use **ONE OR THE OTHER** property, not both:

```
IdSSL.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1_2;
//IdSSL.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvSSLv3]; // <-- get rid of this
```

Or:

```
//IdSSL.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1_2; // <-- get rid of this
IdSSL.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1_2]; // <-- and change this from SSL 3.0 to TLS 1.2
```

In the latter case, you should prefer to enable all of the available TLS 1.x versions, for wider acceptance by more HTTPS servers that use TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 but not TLS 1.2 yet:

```
IdSSL.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1, sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1_2];
```

Or, to future-proof the code as new TLS versions are added to OpenSSL:

```
IdSSL.SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv23; // enable all available versions first
IdSSL.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := IdSSL.SSLOptions.SSLVersions - [sslvSSLv2, sslvSSLv3]; // then remove compromised versions
```

Comment: Check update 2, is ti because of the proxy server and port ? , i used this time 151.80.100.147:62007 but still

Comment: The SSL/TLS handshake is not performed until *after* `TIdHTTP` has instructed the proxy to create a raw TCP tunnel to the target HTTPS server and that connection is successful, THEN the handshake is performed with the HTTPS server directly. An "unknown protocol" error means OpenSSL received data that is not a `ServerHello` packet of the handshake. For instance, if the server (or the proxy) sent back unencrypted HTML instead. Either the proxy sent something it shouldn't have (or `TIdHTTP` did not read it from the socket correctly), or the server does not have SSL/TLS enabled on the HTTPS port.